# Qpid JMS behind a proxy

Tags: java, jms, qpid

I'm developing a Spring-Boot application which should do some kind of messaging with the Qpid JMS Client using amqp 1.0 over websocket. As I must use a proxy in some scenarios, I would like to know if it is possible to define a proxy for a Qpid JMS client.